# Xamarin Android using Camera2 API, need to perform Auto Focus.

Tags: android, xamarin, samsung-mobile, android-camera2

**Problem: Unable to get states(CaptureResult.ControlAfState) correctly in sumsang devices even after viewing preview focused. It always returns PassiveFocused(value 2) or others but not FocusLocked(value 4).
In other case, setting ControlAfMode to Auto, I'm able to get state FocusLocked(4) even it is a blur image**

**Here is preview request code,
Tried Scenerio's**

```
  1) PreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfMode,
        (int)ControlAFMode.ContinuousPicture);
        CaptureSession.SetRepeatingRequest(PreviewRequestBuilder.Build(),
        mCaptureCallback,backgroundHandler);


  2) PreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfMode, (int)ControlAFMode.Auto);
    CaptureSession.SetRepeatingRequest(PreviewRequestBuilder.Build(), mCaptureCallback, backgroundHandler);
    PreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfTrigger, (int)ControlAFTrigger.Start);
    CaptureSession.Capture(PreviewRequestBuilder.Build(), mCaptureCallback, backgroundHandler);
    PreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfTrigger, (int)ControlAFTrigger.Idle);
    CaptureSession.SetRepeatingRequest(PreviewRequestBuilder.Build(), mCaptureCallback, backgroundHandler);


      3) PreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlMode,(int)ControlMode.Auto);
PreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfMode,
(int)ControlAFMode.Auto);
PreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfTrigger,
(int)ControlAFTrigger.Start);
PreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAePrecaptureTrigger,(int)ControlAEPrecaptureTrigger.Start);
PreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfTrigger,(int)ControlAFTrigger.Idle);
CaptureSession.SetRepeatingRequest(PreviewRequestBuilder.Build(), mCaptureCallback, backgroundHandler);
```

Please help!!. If any questions in above explanation leave comments. Thanks inadvance

Comment: could it automatically focus on other phones?

Comment: Yes. I tried with above Scenerio 1

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a specific issue to the hardware Samsung is using, but some of their devices don't even focus with the stock camera until you click to take the photo